# How to test function on component with jest?

Tags: react-native

I'm working with react-native but I have a problem: when I try to test a component, I don't have idea how to test a function on a props.

I'm working with react hooks, so the name of my component is `CardData` so when you onPress in the CollapseHeader the component show me more information it's like to accordion, so in `onToggle={(isCollapsed) => changeCollapsed(isCollapsed)}`, i call a function, this function wait a parameter:boolean isCollapsed is the value when the collapsed is open o close so isCollapsed return true or false, so i need to test that change when the user press the collapsed, isCollapsed change the state for true and when the collapsed is closed, isCollapased change state to false, that test i need to create

```
return (
    <Card style={styles.cardFather}>
        <Collapse onToggle={(isCollapsed: boolean) => changeCollapsed(isCollapsed)}>
            <CollapseHeader style={styles.baseCard}>
                <View style={styles.contentView}>
                    <Text style={styles.numberOrder}>94378331</Text>
                    <Text>JOE LOCKWOOD</Text>
                    <Icon type="FontAwesome" name="file-text" style={styles.fileIcon} />
                    <Icon type="FontAwesome5" name="truck" style={styles.truckIcon} />
                    <Icon type="FontAwesome5" name="shopping-cart" style={styles.shoopingIcon} />
                    {!isCollapsed ? (
                        <Icon type="FontAwesome5" name="chevron-down" style={styles.chevronIcon} />
                    ) : (
                        <Icon type="FontAwesome5" name="chevron-up" style={styles.chevronIcon} />
                    )}
                </View>
            </CollapseHeader>
            <CollapseBody>
                <View style={styles.baseOrderPlace}>
                    <Icon type="AntDesign" name="clockcircle" style={styles.clockOrderPlace} />
                    <Text style={styles.titleOrderPlace}>Order placed</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.timeOrderPlace}>4 hours ago</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.baseSpecial}>
                    <Icon type="FontAwesome" name="file-text" style={styles.fileIconSpecial} />
                    <Text style={styles.titleSpecial}>Special instructions</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.textSpecial}>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sed varius nisi, id tincidunt
                        ligula. Suspendisse vestibulum erat molestie elit suscipit, volutpat pellentesque dui
                        euismod.
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </CollapseBody>
        </Collapse>
    </Card>
);
```

```
const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(false);

function changeCollapsed(collapsed: boolean) {
    if (collapsed) {
        setIsCollapsed(true);
    } else {
        setIsCollapsed(false);
    }
```

I don't have any test.